# Python - Use external function as class method

Tags: python, function, class, methods

Say I have some very long function `module.my_function` that's something like this:

```
def my_function(param1,param2,param3='foo',param4='bar',param5=None,...)
```

With a large number of args and keyword args. I want this function to be usable both as a part of module `module` and as a class method for `myClass`. The code for the function will remain exactly the same, but in `myClass` a few keyword args may take different default values.

What's the best way of doing this? Previously I was doing something like:

```
class myCLass(object):
    def __init__(self,...
    def my_function(self, param1,param2,param3='hello',param4='qaz',param5=['baz'],...):
        module.my_function(param1,param2,param3=param3,param4=param4,param5=param5,...)
```

It seems a little silly to write all these arguments that many times, especially with a very large number of arguments. I also considered doing something like `module.my_function(**locals())` inside the class method, but I'm not sure how to handle the `self` argument and I don't know if this would lead to other issues.

I could just copy paste the entire code for the function, but that doesn't really seem very efficient, when all that's changing is a few default values and the code for `my_function` is *very* long. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a reason that all of the keyword args have to be explicit and you can't just use kwargs?

Comment: The reason is probably that I'm not too experienced a coder... how would I use kwargs in this situation and set some of the default values to something different? Say 3-5  in the above example are the ones I'm changing.. would I just specify params 1-5 and use kwargs for the rest?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the function to bound method by calling its `__get__` method (since all function as [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) as well, thus have this method)

```
def t(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args)
    print(kwargs)

class Test():
    pass
Test.t = t.__get__(Test(), Test) # binding to the instance of Test
```

For example

```
Test().t(1,2, x=1, y=2)
(<__main__.Test object at 0x7fd7f6d845f8>, 1, 2)
{'y': 2, 'x': 1}
```

Note that the instance is also passed as an positional argument. That is if you want you function to be instance method, the function should have been written in such a way that first argument behaves as instance of the class. Else, you can bind the function to None instance and the class, which will be like `staticmethod`.

```
Test.tt = t.__get__(None, Test)
Test.tt(1,2,x=1, y=2)
(1, 2)
{'y': 2, 'x': 1}
```

Furthermore, to make it a `classmethod` (first argument is class):

```
Test.ttt = t.__get__(Test, None) # bind to class
Test.ttt(1,2, x=1, y=2)
(<class '__main__.Test'>, 1, 2)
{'y': 2, 'x': 1}
```